# eslint airbnb-base gives many errors due to use strict mode. What should I do?

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I initialised eslint with airbnb-base using `npx eslint --init`.
I use normal javascript. After `npx eslint "file.js"` command I get a lot of errors due to use strict mode.
What should I do?

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: 'airbnb-base',
  overrides: [
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
  },
  rules: {
  },
};
```

```
'use strict';
(function () {
  function counter() {
    const resultCounter = {
      increase: 0,
      decrease: 0,
      value: 0
    };
  }
  counter();
})();
```

Comment: first suggestion - add example code and errors you get. Otherwise, your question is too broad and can't be really answered